# Django - Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database, server

I am trying to deploy my Django app and connect it to the mssql server.
Django app is running on the iis and MSSQL Server 16 
I am getting this error: 
`('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

I am running Django==2.1.11 and pyodbc==4.0.27

This is my settings,py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'USER': 'app_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXX',
    'HOST': 'XYZ.XYZ.XYZ.XYZ',
    'PORT': '1433',

'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    }
}
```

}

I have no idea what to do to make it working.